# How to put given characters into alphabetical order with the uppercase letters in the front

Tags: c++

There will be a given input by the user and I have to put it into alphabetical order with the uppercase characters in the front, lowercase after. C++
For example, the input is GoodMorning, the output will be  GMdginnooor.

Comment: The default sort order for characters puts uppercase letters in front. Have you looked at `std::sort`? If you are not allowed to use it please update your question.

Comment: Let's see your attempt.

Comment: @Botje The problem is that I don't think simply calling `std::sort` will work for a different encoding system, such as EBCDIC, where the lower case is lower in the collating sequence than upper case.

Comment: Fair point. But I consider EBCDIC out of scope for homework questions like these :)

Comment: @Botje #include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

void sortString(string &str){ 
   sort(str.begin(), str.end()); 
   cout << str; 
} 
int main() { 
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    sortString(s); 
    return 0; 
}

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at this? The code I just commented

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61745912/edit) your question with that code along with any errors you get or expected/actual result.

Comment: You can still supply a custom comparator to `std::sort`.  Good luck getting that past code review: "yeah, I decided to bloat this code just cos there's a 1 in a million chance this program will ever target non-ASCII encodings without needing to be completely rewritten anyway" ;)

Comment: @paddy -- Depends on the software that is being produced.  If it's one of those libraries that's cross-platform like a compression/encryption library or similar that is guaranteed to work in any environment, well you may get the review rejected if ASCII is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, just use the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
    std::string text;

    std::cout << "Input a string: ";
    getline(std::cin, text);

    std::sort(text.begin(), text.end());

    std::cout << text;

    return 0;
}
```

> **Sample Output**

```
Input a string: GoodMorning
GMdginnooor
```

Hope it helps you!